# Не присваивается значение текстового поля

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Не пойму в чем ошибка, выдаёт в место "username"-"nuul".

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Who are you?"  >
        <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="What do you want to say?" />
        <button> <input type="submit" id="m" autocomplete="off" onclick="sendMessage()">Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function()
      {
        <!-- Отправка сообщения --> 
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#message').val());
        <!-- Очищаем текстовое окно сообщения --> 
        $('#message').val('');
        return false;
      });


      var username = document.getElementById('#user');

          <!-- Приём сообщения с сервера -->
          socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {

              $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(username + ":" + msg));


          });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Код тут никогда не выполнится, т.к. он вырван из контекста.  
Как говорил дед - мне нужно больше! Кода, разумеется.

Comment: исправил)))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переписал по своему всё

```
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
    <input type="text" id="user" placeholder="Who are you?">
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="What do you want to say?">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var socket = io();
    var $messages = $('#messages');
    var $message = $('#message');
    var $user = $('#user');
    $('form').submit(function() {
        // Отправка сообщения
        socket.emit('chat message', { user: $user.val(), text: $message.val() });
        // Очищаем текстовое окно сообщения
        $message.val('');
        return false;
    });
    // Приём сообщения с сервера
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
        $messages.append($('<li>').text(msg.user + ': ' + msg.text));
    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: но появился еще один вопрос,когда пользователю 2 приходит письмо от пользователя 1,сообщение подписано не пользователем 1 а вторым т.е. если я вам отправлю письмо то мое сообщение будет подписано вами.

есть php код который делает userId уникальным
"<?php
$SECRET_KEY = 'some_secret_code';

$userId = rand(00001,99999);

$authParams = array(
    'user_id' => $userId,
    'auth_key' => md5(uniqid('chat', true)),
    'username' => 'Peter_'.$userId,
    'tm' => time(),
);"
как его реализовать в js ?

Comment: Это предсказуемо было )) исправил ответ, чтоб правильный пользователь приходил.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй сделать

```
document.getElementById('user').value
```

вместо

```
document.getElementById('#user')
```

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp)

Comment: вот что выдает [object HTMLInputElement]:

Comment: @Сергей74rus, Нужно с `.value`.

Comment: @TheDoctor, спасибо, поправил ответ

Comment: @TheDoctor, не помогло в консоли пишет Cannot read property 'value' of null